# Issue with Import Python from a github Repo

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am sorry for asking for the billion times an issue about python import but I am lost.

Here is my file structure:

```
My_Folder/
   main.py
   utils/
        ...Some_Files...
   folderA/
        predictions.py

GitHub_Repo_Folder/
   predictor.py
   utils/
        ...somes_Files...
        dataset.py
```

My different files:

**Predictor.py:**

```
from utils.dataset import function
class MyClass():
     ....Some Code...
```

**Predictions.py:**

```
import sys
sys.append("My_Folder/")

from predictor import *
```

**main.py**

```
from predictions import *
predictions.start()
```

My issue is that it does not work.
Python tells me that there is no **dataset** in utils when I try to import predictor in Predictions.py.

I guess it's because of the confusion of the different **utils** but I do not know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance guys !!

Comment: `import predictions` `predictions.start()` the `import *` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks :) 
I changed it but still an error when I try to import it.
It keeps telling me that utils.dataset does not exist